# How do I run a function on object creation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

#### Issue:

I'm creating an HTML5 canvas game and I want to create an object for my ship which assigns the src of the ship to images/powship.png. It works if I create the ship and then assign the i variable an src, but I wanted to know if I could do it all at once when I'm building the ship.

Works if I do something like this:

```
ship = { //a class for my ship
    x : $(window).width()/2,
    y : $(window).height()/2,
    i : new Image()
}
ship.i.src="images/powship.png";
```

I wanted to do it all at once when I create my ship (to keep things together). Something like this:

```
ship = { //a class for my ship
    x : $(window).width()/2,
    y : $(window).height()/2,
    i : new Image(),
    src : function() {
        return this.i.src="images/powship.png"
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

[Code that works is here](https://github.com/planetoftheweb/CanvasGame)

[Demo here](http://planetoftheweb.com/exercises/canvasgame/)

[Unminified JS file](http://planetoftheweb.com/exercises/canvasgame/_/js/script.js)

#### Question:

How do I run a function on object creation?

Answer (score 2):

the function `ship.src();` is not being run, and is why the `.src` is not getting set.

Your ship class may desire more things to run on creation, so a constructor is appropriate.

```
var Ship = function(){
    // set up basic components of your class
    this.x = $(window).width()/2;
    this.y = $(window).height()/2;
    this.i = new Image(); 

    // preform any construction requirements
    this.i.src = "images/powship.png";
};

var ship = new Ship();
```

Or you could curry like this:

```
var ship = function(){
    result = {
       x : $(window).height()/2,
       y : $(window).height()/2,
       i : new Image()
    }
    result.i.src = "images/powship.png";
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a constructor function which will let you reuse the code.

```
function Ship() {
    var win = $(window);
    this.x = win.width()/2;
    this.y = win.height()/2;
    this.i = new Image();
    this.src = this.i.src = "images/powship.png";
}

var ship1 = new Ship();
var ship2 = new Ship();
```

You can't do what you are trying to do since the object doesn't exist until after you create it so you can't refer to its properties while creating it with the literal notation.

Comment: I thought about that, but I only really need one ship since it's the main character. I guess I could use the same constructor for ships of different kinds and then use this constructor.

Comment: @user1460419 then my curry example may be more appropriate.

Comment: I was just wondering if it was possible to do it all at once inside an object.

Answer (score -1):

```
i : new Image({src : "images/powship.png" })
```

try that, should work.

Comment: That looked really good though. Thanks for the help. I might go with some of the constructor options, but I was just wondering if it could be done in one fell swoop. ;)

Comment: sometimes the most concise way isn't always the best. It's easier to read it if you have it in a separate line like in your first block of code.

Comment: Yes, but it was more of a...can I do it question.

Comment: `i : { src : "images/powship.png" }` and then when you create or update the ship you could call `new Image(Ship.i.src);`

Comment: `i : $(new Image).attr('src', 'images/powship.png')` and without jQuery, `i : (new Image).setAttribute('src', 'images/powship.png')`